# Angular 2 - ngFor not generating (click) on an anchor

Tags: angular, ngfor

I am facing a strange behavior with the *ngFor structural directive of Angular.

This code...

```
<a *ngFor="let item of addMenuItems" href="#" (click)="onAddClicked(item)">{{item}}</a>
```

... generates this when the array contains two items:

```
<a href="#">item 1</a>
<a href="#">item 2</a>
```

or in other words, it generates all except the (click)="onAddClicked(item)" part ..

What may be the reason of this weird behavior ?

Thanks

Riana

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/9HSbC1Nw0ukgwVAKQIqT?p=preview it doesn't appear to be there but still the click event handler is invoked when clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is common for event binding not to be explicitly visible when inspecting the DOM / the element in which an event is bound.

Check the event listeners and you should see something like:

```
a
Function    vendor.js:86289
Type        Bubbling
```

Where the reference to `vendor.js` is your `onAddClicked`.

It is important to remember that angular is compiled prior to displaying in your browser, so it identifies the `(click)` binding / attribute and then transmutes this into an `addEventListener()` binding for that element.

Answer (score 0):

So as you know the * in the *ngFor is just sugar syntax for the template that is generated behind the scenes. Having this it will mean that it is attaching the click event to each corresponding child of the template (the a anchors) but it’s not generating the markup for it. It’s attaching to the element itself. Most likely you will be able to see it in the events tab on the browser developer tools